# How to translate a woocommerce website using the .mo and .po files?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So, I now how to use the .po and .mo files and where they are located but I don't know how to use them. For example I want to have 3 buttons on my website that link to 3 languages - but how can I ensure that the website will load the corresponding .mo and .po files for that specific language?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will need to use a plugin to translate your website completely with language switchers.
I'm personally a big fan of Translatepress + Loco translate, used as a combination - Loco translate to create po/mo files for static content and Translatepress to translate dynamic content, as well as pages etc which don't appear in string translations (po/mo files).
Translatepress has a shortcode to include for the language switcher which you can place anywhere on your website.